# C++: Array subclass of single superclass?

Tags: c++, arrays, class, object, subclass

I'm trying to simulate a deck of cards using two classes, "class Deck" and "class Card : public Deck". I want the /deck/ class to have a method to initialize the cards in a 52 object array in order, which I'll later be able to shuffle as well.

How would I go about this? (I need to use classes for this assignment--we haven't learned vectors yet)

Comment: Why would a `Card` be a specialization of a `Deck`?

Comment: A Deck might be a container for Card. `std::vector<Card> deck;` No inheritance needed there.

Comment: @juanchopanza Card is a child class to deck because I want deck to contain methods that handle the cards as objects within an array.

Comment: OK, then you should make it inherit from `Dealer` too, just to be on the safe side. You'll need a `Casino` base class too. `class Card : public Deck, public Dealer, public Casino`. That should work.

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe So, Card wouldn't need to be a subclass? I could just create an array of Card objects in main, and send them to be handled by Deck methods?

Comment: @user3728321 You probably meant `Card` should be a **nested** class of `Deck`, not an ***inherited*** class!

Answer (score 4):

The approach of making `Card` derive from `Deck` is incorrect. When you type in `class Card : public Deck`, you are making a **is-a** relationship between Card and Deck, so that `Card` is a `Deck`. Naturally, this is not right.

You want a deck to be a sequence of cards, and you don't even need a new data type for that.

```
std::vector<Card> deck;
```

If you want, you can make an alias:

```
using Deck = std::vector<Card>;
Deck deck;
```

And finally, create a function that returns a complete 52-card deck:

```
Deck create52CardDeck(void) {
    Deck deck;
    // your code here, use push_back to add cards to the deck
    return deck;
}
```

If you insist on having a class for Deck, that can be done too by encapsulating [std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector):

```
class Deck {
    std::vector<Card> vector;

public:
    // make an empty deck
    Deck(void) = default;

    // then you can make your own methods:
    static Deck create52CardDeck(void) { ... }
    void shuffle() { ... } 
    Card takeFromTop(void) { ... }
    void putCardOntop(Card c) { ... }  // or const Card& argument

};
```

Yet another alternative is to use an array of cards, or even a linked list, instead of [std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector). These make some operations more complicated to implement, however. Although I am adding it here, there are some implications to having an array of `Card`s. One of them is that not all slots in the array may actually have a card if some cards were taken from the 52.

```
class Deck {
    Card cards[52];
    unsigned int ncards;

public:
    // make an empty deck 
    Deck(void) : ncards(0)
    {}

    // the other methods will have to manipulate the array properly

};
```

Comment: I actually haven't learned vectors yet and this is part of an assignment, so I kind of have to go about it using classes. My apologies for not clarifying.

Comment: The classes still need an implementation. There are other alternatives to that: having an array instead of a vector. But vector is the nicest approach, because all you need is to know how to use it.

Comment: @user3728321 Vectors are much easier to use than C-style arrays.

Comment: On the subject, you should ask your professor/teacher whether you are allowed to used the C++ standard library containers. If so, feel free to use `std::vector`. Otherwise, use an array and manipulate it properly.

Answer (score 3):

If you can't use `vector` and insist on having a separate class for a deck, then you should have a `Deck` holding an array of `Card`s:

```
class Deck {
    Card cards[52];
};
```